# How can I add another file to my pull request?

Tags: git, pull-request

I spotted an error on a repository that I do not own, so I modified a file (`README.md`) directly on Github, then submitted a pull request.

A member of the repository then asked me to also change an additional file (`README.Rmd`).

Can I do this as part of the original pull request or do I have to submit a new pull request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the original PR is still pending (not yet merged), just commit and push again on the candidate (source) branch, the PR will update itself. (don't forget to refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on a GitHub Azure repo.  It auto-created a separate branch for me, but the original PR was still open.  I just PR-ed the second branch into my first branch, and it worked.